# Firebase, react and redux wait for store to update

Tags: reactjs, firebase, authentication, redux, redux-thunk

I have a React app connected to Firebase, i want to check if user is logged in at every page refresh, dispatching `IS_SIGNED_IN` action, here's the action creator:

```
export function checkAuth() {
return dispatch => {
    firebaseAuth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
        if (user) {
            dispatch(signedInAction())
        } else {
            dispatch(signedOutAction())
        }
    })
  }
}
```

Inside the reducer i just make boolean `isAuthenticated` to true/false:

```
case ActionTypes.isSignedIn: {
    return Object.assign({}, state, {
        isAuthenticated: true
    })
}
case ActionTypes.isSignedOut: {
    return Object.assign({}, state, {
        isAuthenticated: false
    })
}
```

Because i want to check if user is signed in when app loads i dispatch the action at `componentDidMount` (which is wrong i guess):

```
class Main extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}

componentDidMount() {
    store.dispatch(checkAuth());
}

render() {
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <Router>
                <Theme>
                    <Routes />
                </Theme>
            </Router>
        </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

This makes my code where i check for `isAuthenticated` fail, because it's not yet set in the store, this is in `Routes` component for example. What would be the best way to solve this? To add up, i know i can use conditional rendering and check to see when `isAuthenticated` is defined, but i don't like that solution. Thoughts? Thanks

Comment: You can use componentWillMount instead of componentDidMount and use conditional rendering :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done what you are trying to do with a live application and used in it Firebase Auth. You need to use the Actions as a login and logout only then use componentWillMount() and componentWillReceiveProps() to check if the user is logged in:

Actions:

```
import { auth } from '../fire';
export const GET_USER = 'get_user';

export function getUser(){
    return dispatch => {
        auth.onAuthStateChanged(user=>{
            dispatch({
                type: GET_USER,
                payload: user
            });
        });
    };
}

export function login(email,password){
    return dispatch => auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
}

export function logout(){
    return dispatch => auth.signOut();
}

export function createAccount(email, password){
    return dispatch => auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
}
```

your Reducer should have this:

```
import {GET_USER} from '../Actions/UserActions';

export default function( state = {loading:true}, action){
    switch (action.type){
        case GET_USER:
            return { loading: false, ...action.payload };
        default:
        return state;
    }
}
```

in your App.js for example, just in the start of it use this:

```
 componentWillMount(){
   this.props.getUser();
   if(this.props.user.loading === false && this.props.user.email === undefined){
     this.props.history.replace('/Login');
   }
 }

 componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
  if(nextProps.user.loading === false && nextProps.user.email === undefined){
    this.props.history.replace('/Login');
  }
 }
```

this is because you have your Auth credentials in your props already.

I hope this works for you..