# How to build web interface for my Swift App/Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, frontend

I learned how to code in swift a little while back and created my first app. Now I'm trying to market it to customers, I realized that a web-interface might be what I need to scale this up to start attracting clients.

I use firebase as my backend now and would like to see what I can do to have a web interface that:

- Allows customers to log in to see their unique data.
- Updates info on my firebase backend
- is Scaleable.

I'm not sure where to start nor how long this process will take. Any one has any ideas on where to get started?

Comment: This question is way too broad and will probably end up getting closed or down voted. There are many articles out there regarding how to make a web page talk to a database. Your swift app would use a web service to talk to the same database.

Comment: As the question stated, I did not know that. Isn't this a place to come for answers? For people who are curious and looking for answers, to obtain answers? I don't see it as a broad question. Open ended, yes. Broad may not be exact.

Comment: Your question is broad because it covers multiple topics in one question. This is the place to post code and have others comment and help you fix coding errors, open ended questions like this will get down voted and closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase is a realtime database and it is mostly used with mobile apps and some of the JavaScript applications like Angular and ReactJS. I think the best is to use ReactJS and there you can do a lot of the same functionalities you did on your app.

You can find a lot of tutorials online about how to do reactjs and firebase apps.

Have a look at this post and it should give you an idea about how it is done. It is gonna be a new thing if you are not familiar with javascript NodeJS / ReactJS development. ([Firebase, react and redux wait for store to update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47704042/firebase-react-and-redux-wait-for-store-to-update/47716718#47716718))

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure Wordpress has a firebase plugin that could come in handy. Using Wordpress would save a lot of time actually designing a website, getting servers, and backend stuff like that. If you pay a little bit you can get rid of the .wordpress. com tag too, and your website can easily look professional.